Youtube Data API pageToken not registering
I am trying to scrape all of the comments on a youtube video, but when I provide a pageToken it ignores it and just returns the data I already have.
Example:
When I use the following URL
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&maxResults=100&parentId=[Parent ID of comment]&pageToken=[The nextPageToken of the previous fetch]&key[My API key]
It returns the same thing as this:
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&maxResults=100&parentId=[Parent ID of comment]&key[My API key]
Since it keeps returning the same data, it also returns the same pageToken and the program I wrote gets into an infinite loop.
Here is the relevant part of the code:
if (snippet.totalReplyCount > 5) {
    var json3 = await fetchAPI("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&maxResults=100&parentId=" + snippet.topLevelComment.id)
    if (json3.error) {
        throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json3.error))
    }
    else do {
        var comments = json3.items
        for (var j in comments) {
            if (++count % 100 == 0) console.log ("scraping comment " + count + " of " + videoID)
            video[comments[j].snippet.authorChannelId.value] = {handle: comments[j].snippet.authorDisplayName}
        }
        if (json3.nextPageToken) {
            json3 = await fetchAPI("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&maxResults=100&parentId=" + snippet.topLevelComment.id + "&pageToken=" + encodeURIComponent(json3.nextPageToken))
            if (json3.error) {
                throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json3.error))
            }
        }
    } while (json3.nextPageToken)
}

async function fetchAPI(url) {
    var error = true;
    while (error || (response.error && checkError(response.error, "processingFailure")))
    try {
        var response = await fetch(url + "&key=" + key)
        error = false;
    } catch (e) {
        
    }
    response = await response.json()
    if (response.error && response.error.code == 400) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.error))
        console.log(checkError(response.error, "processingFailure"))
    }
    return response
}

function checkError(error, reason) {
    return error.errors.map((a) => a.reason).includes(reason)
}


Send your code.

Ok, I added my code. I don't think there's a problem with the code because the same thing happened when I just went to the URL in my browser.

Indeed I confirm your issue with https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/comments?part=snippet&maxResults=6&parentId=UgwZdtV029YjTRX3B514AaABAg and https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/comments?part=snippet&maxResults=6&parentId=UgwZdtV029YjTRX3B514AaABAg&pageToken=Z2V0X2NvbW1lbnRfd2l0aF9yZXBsaWVzX3N0cmVhbS0tQ2dnSWdBUVZGN2ZST0JJRkNLQWdHQUVZQUNJT0Nnd0k1TXFwc2dZUTBNWDd5d0U=. Google has a bug tracker for YouTube Data API v3 at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803 but their API looks less stable than YouTube UI webscraping...

So I opened the issue https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/275 on my open-source YouTube UI webscraping API to solve your issue.

Looks like a bug it has been logged on the issue forum.  I have sent a ping to google to try and get it escalated
